# Unable to SFTP (but can SSH) - Using port other than 22

Tags: iptables, sftp

I followed the iptables here:

http://wiki.debian.org/iptables

I replaced the standard Port 22 in sshd_config with Port 1234

Currently I'm able to SSH via Port 1234, but unable to SFTP using Filezilla; it keeps saying it failed to authenticate. I've verified that the password is correct.

Does anyone know why SFTP is not working?

Comment: Note netfilter works with ports, not services (other than the conntrack modules). So when you're allowing ssh, what you're really allowing is TCP port 22.

Comment: @gparent, thank you. So question is... why can I SSH but not SFTP? It keeps telling me authentication failed?

Comment: I don't know about that part, you don't really include anything to help either. Check sshd's logs.

Answer (score 1):

If you can ssh but not sftp, the issue is very unlikely to be in your firewall, as both services normally run on TCP port 22 - both are subsystems of `sshd`.  You should first look closely at your `sshd` config, to find out why the sftp subsystem isn't active.

Opening up inbound TCP port 1234 is unlikely to be too hard, but for that to **do** anything you're going to need to make `sshd` listen on that port for sftp purposes, and for that, you're going to first need to make it listen on port 22 for sftp purposes.

Comment: Thanks @MadHatter. In my sshd_config, I remove Port 22, and replace with Port 1234. So when I SSH, I SSH into Port 1234. I've also checked that "Subsystem sftp" is not commented out. So I don't know why I can SSH, but not SFTP into Port 1234?

Comment: If your question has become "why doesn't sftp work on my sshd", you'll need to provide a lot more information to help us.  How does it fail?  Can you show us what you're doing, and how it's failing?  If you can edit this information into your question, plus the bit of your `sshd_config` that relates to sftp, we may be able to be more help.

Comment: edited question as per your advice :-)

Comment: Can you ssh to it from the shell?  If so, can you use the same credentials to sftp to it from the same shell?

Comment: if by shell you mean CLI, yeah I can SSH to the Port 1234 and I can do an "scp" to and from that port. Only thing I can't do is SFTP from Filezilla.

Comment: That's not what I asked.  I want to compare like-with-like access, changing only ssh vs. sftp, because I'm trying to take the client (software and system) out of the picture.  So, I ask again: from that shell from which you can ssh to server:1234, can you also sftp to server:1234?